# InvalidOperationException in wcf service of asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I Just created a restful service and trying to access data through entity framework. i dont to where to correct the exception .please help on this
Exception coming:
    An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReferenceCheck.ICheckDetails' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

my client code:
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entities.User u = new Entities.User();
            u.UserName = TextBoxUN.Text;
            u.Password = TextBoxP.Text;
            ServiceReferenceCheck.CheckDetailsClient src=new ServiceReferenceCheck.CheckDetailsClient();//exception coming here

            if(src.CheckLoginDetails(u))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?UN="+u.UserName);
            }
            else
            {
                LabelError.Text = "please check ur id and password once again";
            }

        }

my service web.config (part of it):
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="LoginServices.CheckDetails">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="LoginServices.ICheckDetails"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please add the exception's stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should define endpoint you are trying to access in your client's configuration file. Something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebHttpBinding">
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Services/CheckDetails.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding"
            contract="ICheckDetails"
            name="ICheckDetailsEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call rest service using generated proxy either by using add service reference or by using svcutil. Use http libraries or APIs like web client, httpwebrequest.

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same issue I did some research and it turned out that I had to define a SOAP endpoint alongside with the REST one in the service part.

It looks like generated client proxy classes work only with SOAP service endpoints.

At the end, the service's web.config looked like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Service1" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="restBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that REST endpoint must have different path than SOAP one, otherwise behaviour is undefined.